# -[_SwiftValue where]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In Swift 3, my app crashs on launch screen.
I don't know what does "-[_SwiftValue where]" mean. And it crashs on AppDelegate, I don't know where the wrong code is.

[image]

Comment: add your error code

Comment: The stack trace tells you where. It's in your `LCDBBlockSQLiteCallBackFunction`.

Comment: It is saying `NewLyricTableView`.

Comment: Check your controller's connection inspector. Might be possible that you have created an outlet for your table and renamed it after connection, Which leads to crash.

Comment: @Kaiyuan Xu try to search in your project for [_SwiftValue where] to see where it used.